# Use jquery clear textbox value in a repeater control

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax

I got a problem when I am trying to clear the content of a textbox which is in the repeater control.

The repeater control has its data source and is bound in the code behind. The textbox shows the information from the data source. I am using ajax and button to delete the data behind the textbox and clear the content of it. Although the delete function works, the jquery codes that try to clear text is not working.

The jquery codes I am using is:

```
$(this).parent().prev(".answerText").val("");
```

I am targeting the right element. These codes works if the textbox does not have content originally. If I text something in this text box and click this button it will clear the content.

Is anyone has a clue on how to deal with this?

The data source is bind in onInit :

`protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
    {
        rprQuestions.DataSource = test.Questions;
        rprQuestions.DataBind();
    }`

The HTML code is:
`enter code here`

```
<span class="input-group-btn">

<a href="#" id="btnRemoveAnswer" class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove form-control removeAnswer" name="remove this answer" onclick="return false;"></a></span>

</ItemTemplate>


</asp:Repeater>
```

Comment: Your code should work fine. Any issue would depend on the HTML structure which you haven't provided in the question, or errors elsewhere in your logic.

Comment: But this code does work in other text box that has the same structure but no content originally. I am wondering if it is because of the repeater control's data source.

Comment: How are you triggering the event which contains this code? If it's appended dynamically after page load you need to use a delegated event handler. A full example is much more helpful than a single line of code.

Comment: I have added some code to this question. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

var $tr = $(this).closest('li');

$tr.find("input[id$=txtboxId]").val('');

You can find the closet element which is getting repeated and search for textbox with id and then change the value.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the current context of this, then this should work:

$(this).parent().find('.answerText').html();

Comment: This one still not working. I wonder why this code works on other textbox in the same repeater control but does not have text in it originally.